# Why is text-end not working in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

What have I done wrong? I can't get the text to the right. I am sorry, Real beginner.

```
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-12 text-end">
        <p><a href="teL: 0612345678"> Bel ons </a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working but the problem may be from the library or from the browser you are using, so I prefer to use the official Bootstrap CDN.

[Official Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/)

This is an example of your code with Boostrap CDN:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-12 text-end">
        <p><a href="teL: 0612345678"> Bel ons </a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text-end` class is working, but it's not as far right as it should be.

From the Bootstrap 5 docs...

> "**Rows are wrappers for columns**. Each column has horizontal padding
> (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
> is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins to ensure the
> content in your columns is visually aligned.."

Therefore the `col-12` should be inside a `row`..

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-end">
                <p><a href="teL: 0612345678"> Bel ons </a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/UKjLD2WJl4)

Comment: Accept an answer so others know the question is solved!